# The name of the VLAN is abnormal when added to the eth1

Tags: networking, vlan

When the VLAN is added to the Linux, the VLAN Dev name of VLAN ends normally with the network card. As a result, the abnormal VLAN ends up with the rename word.

normal:
[image: normal vlan]

abnormal:
[image: abnormal vlan]

commands:

ifconfig:
[image: ifconfig]

sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:
[image: eth1]

add vlan:
sudo vconfig add eth1 70:
[image: add vlan]

What happened？

Comment: `udev` decided it had to rename your network adapters. Fix your `udev` rules (or add a custom rule so these adapters don't get renamed).

Answer (score 0):

before using

```
vconfig add eth1 70
```

you might whish to use

```
vconfig set_name_type VLAN_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
```

see `man vconfig` for details.

Comment: Thanks，although `vconfig set_name_type VLAN_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD` can change the vlan dev name, but it's still not what I want. @dirkt's solution works.